# I want to cross reference postcodes from two sheets and record the amount of matchs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I’ve recently started working for a charity helping with their IT. I’m trying to update one of their spread sheets (Excel 2010).

I have 2 lists of postcodes, both lists are in separate columns in different sheets in the same excel file. Each row contains one post code. I want to cross reference the data so that the postcodes on the 1st sheet have a number ‘1’ in the cell next to them IF they match a post code on the 2nd sheet. If they match more than one post code I’d like that number to be a 2,3,4 etc.

I have the 1st list of postcodes in the 1st sheet starting from cell B3 then B4, B5 etc. and on the 2nd sheet again it’s from B3 then B4, B5. I’m NOT looking to see if two ‘B3’ cells match, I’m looking to see how many of the postcodes from the 2nd sheet match the ‘B3’ cell in the first sheet, then if there are say 3 matches, put a ‘3’ into cell C3 on the 1st sheet

And then continue on thought the rest of the sheet1 B column looking for matches and recording such matches in the C column.

Thank you so much for any help or advice you may have it is greatly appreciated and will cut down on hundreds of wasted man hours that I’d like to see put to better use, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with [CountIf](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/countif-function-HA102753077.aspx?CTT=1)

```
=COUNTIF(range,criteria)
```

My screen shot of it working (although I've put everything onto 1 worksheet for clarity)

[image]

For you, it would possibly be something like (where the values to look up or on Sheet2)

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A$1A$10, A1)
```

**EDIT**
As per your comment, even if you have a formula in Row 1 to get the post code, it will still work. In the screen below, I'm using a RIGHT function to get the postcode form the G column, as you can see, the results are the same

[image]

Comment: Thanks dave that's great,

How do u move the range selection onto the second sheet tho?

Comment: @SettleStories Add the sheet name, like Sheet2! (see update)

Comment: Ok its working now, however what if cell A1 was a formula? In this case I'm using '=RIGHT(B4,8)' because i'm grabbing the post code out of an address in the cell to the left of where you A1 cell is.

Comment: It will still work fine @SettleStories

Comment: it appears to just take the form COUNTIF(count range start:count range end, matching cell). SO yours would be like COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$3:$B$100,B3).

Comment: Ahh there was a 'space' at the end of my post code which was causing the IF to fail, all sorted now. it seems I need to clean up my postcodes but that's a question for another time and place.

 thanks again so much for all you help, I cant describe how much this has helped so many.

Comment: @SettleStories, then use [TRIM function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) :)

Comment: As I copy the formula down the C column its changing the criteria cell as it should do but its also changing range cells which I want to always stay the same, any ideas?

Comment: Did you include the $ around the range? EG `A$1A$100`. @SettleStories